# I can't take high quality picture by android camera

Tags: android, camera

I'm taking a picture via camera with low or sometimes medium quality and camera return correct `uri` and picture to my app.

When i set my camera high quality in Samsung phones not return picture and in HTC phones give me an error `nullpointerexception: uri` (or crash my app in another phones) but in low quality works perfectly.

my code:

```
imCamera.setOnClickListener(new
View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);    

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }
    show.dismiss();
  }
});
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  ...

  try {
    Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
    getContentResolver(), imageUri);

    String photoPath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
    switch (orientation) {

      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
      rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(thumbnail, 90);
      break;

      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
      rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(thumbnail, 180);
      break;

      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
      rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(thumbnail, 270);
      break;

      case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
      default:
      rotatedBitmap = thumbnail;
    }


    if (rotatedBitmap != null) {
      ivImage.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);

      File tempFile = GetTempFile(rotatedBitmap);

      if (tempFile != null)
      crImage = tempFile;
    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

**update**: 
i tested it on android: 4,5,6,7
But it still give me error when quality is high.

**update**: 
Maybe because I'm doing this in the main thread?

Comment: How do you choose high quality? Often, the camera app only uses the default size for capture intent.